# Cant access cloud shell or any compute instances

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, google-cloud-shell

For the last hour or so i can't access my google cloud shell or any of my compute instances (they seem to be running ok - i just can't ssh in via the ssh button in browser).

For cloud shell i get "Google Cloud Shell is temporarily unavailable. Try connecting in a few minutes."

For my compute instances i get "An error occurred while communicating with the SSH server. Check the server and the network configuration."

No idea what's going on - i have restarted everything a few times.

Feels like it could be something on google's side but the status dashboard looks clear: https://status.cloud.google.com/

Comment: i happen to have a windows server compute instance and when i rdp into that and try do the ssh via chrome in there it works. so its as if its a network setting in my vpc or something maybe - but would not have thought that would impact my cloud shell.

Comment: i am able to get in via putty so feels like its a chrome issue

Comment: I am not able to reproduce. Have you tried different browsers? Maybe a [private window](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/95464?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=en).

Comment: Yep tried incognito and got same error, have also tried a different laptop and get the same error.

Comment: also tried edge and firefox this morning - same issues. really stumped here - am using putty as a workaround so not too bad for now but much prefer the browser ssh.

Comment: Have a shot disabling anti-virus and security software, as well as extensions in your browsers. You could also test connecting from different networks.

Comment: i actually opened a ticket with cloud support and they said it is some sort of bug others are also experiencing. I'll see if i can get an issue tracker link to post here in case others having same issues.

Comment: Probably [67997017](https://issuetracker.google.com/67997017) related to the Guest Envoriment?

Comment: i think so - i have a case open (14130394). Will update here if/when we find a solution.